# Getting error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of with no type

Tags: c++, function, class, constructor, declaration

I'm getting the following errors:

> ISO C++ forbids declaration of ttTreeInsert with no type
>
> ISO C++ forbids declaration of ttTreeDelete with no type
>
> ISO C++ forbids declaration of ttTreePrint with no type
>
> prototype for int ttTree::ttTreePrint() does not match any in class ttTree
>
> candidate is: void ttTree::ttTreePrint()

Here is my header file:

```
#ifndef ttTree_h
#define ttTree_h

class ttTree 
{
public:
  ttTree(void);
  int ttTreeInsert(int value);
  int ttTreeDelete(int value);
  void ttTreePrint(void);
  
};

#endif
```

Here is my .cpp file:

```
#include "ttTree.h"

ttTree::ttTree(void)
{
  
}

ttTree::ttTreeInsert(int value)
{
}

ttTree::ttTreeDelete(int value)
{
}

ttTree::ttTreePrint(void)
{
}
```

Can anyone point out what is causing these errors?  Thank you!

Comment: Earlier version of c++ treated the non return type function as void. But ISO C++ forbids declaration  with no type to avoid the unexpected behavior of the programs and function .Here a quick fix would be to mention the appropriate return type of the functions that you  are declaring .

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You forgot the return types in your member function definitions:

```
int ttTree::ttTreeInsert(int value) { ... }
^^^
```

and so on.

Comment: Then why does it say "ISO C++ forbids **declaration** of ... with no type", not "definition" or "implementation"?

Answer (score 7):

Your declaration is `int ttTreeInsert(int value);`

However, your definition/implementation is

```
ttTree::ttTreeInsert(int value)
{
}
```

Notice that the return type `int` is missing in the implementation. Instead it should be

```
int ttTree::ttTreeInsert(int value)
{
    return 1; // or some valid int
}
```